# Phonegap - why use native phonegap alert function

Tags: cordova

I'm testing native alerts for android:

```
showAlert: function (message, title) {
    if (navigator.notification) {
        navigator.notification.alert(message, null, title, 'OK');
    } else {
        alert(title ? (title + ": " + message) : message);
    }
},

initialize: function() {
    var self = this;
    //Phonegap alert
    self.showAlert('Store Initialized', 'Info');

    //Stadard Alert 
    alert('Store Initialized');
}
```

The showAlert() and alert() produce the exact same alert window. So why use phonegap native alert function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What DZL said it's true, you can't customize the title of the alert dialog if you use `alert();` but it's not the only reason.

If you're using phonegap it's safe to assume you're aiming for a cross platform app. The provided apis are reliable, cordova will mantain it for you and it will guarantee that your alert is displayed correctly in every platform, while if you use the standard javascript `alert()` you cannot predict what will be displayed in the screen. (most likely an alert with a default title message saying "this_page.html says:", but you can never know.)

Comment: That's true but from my experience I had a lot more problems using navigator.notification.alert on multiple devices than the regular javascript alert.

Comment: That's not usual I guess, I've been using it for years and it's very stable xplatform. I've had issues with other plugins, geolocation, accelerometer, but never with the notification.

Comment: What kind of issues are you having with the notification plugin? Feel free to post any bugs to the bug tracker at: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB

Answer (score 3):

Because if you use `alert('Message')`, it will give you the message box with the title "index.html says" and you can not remove it but to use `navigation.notification.alert`.

Also with `notification.alert` you can provide the button name and the callback that will be triggered when you dismiss the box

```
navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName])
```